# Переключение раскладки в урезанной гном-сессии

Tags: linux, gnome

В иксах раскладка добавленна

```
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)"        };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)+group(alt_shift_toggle)"        };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

Но не переключается в гном сессии. Сессия урезанна до

```
RequiredComponents=mutter;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.UsbProtection;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom;org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings
```

Если запустить gnome-shell в этой же сессии, то переключалка работает.

UPD **mutter** перехватывает. с metacity иксовые настройки работают. но нужен mutter для того чтоб работал gnome-remote-desktop